# How to get to hibernate on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, battery, hibernate, microsoft-surface-pro-3

At the moment I've got two options.

1. Sleep
2. Shut down

The first is associated with the closing of the lid. I'm unsatisfied with this option because the computer is still eating the power, hence draining the battery.

The second is activated by the power button being pressed. I'm unhappy with it because all the programs I've got on the screen are closed and I need to pull up my working environment all over again.

I recall that **at some point** (possibly on an earlier version of Windows), I had a third option, to hibernate. It was a middle ground between the two listed above. It actually turned off the whole computer to reduce battery lifetime consumption. It also stored all the junk I had in the memory into the drive for a pick up when resuming later on.

What happened to that option? Was it flawed somehow? I'm running on Surface Pro 3 and Windows 8.1, in case that matters.

Comment: It wasn't flawed. The way it works on the SP3 is that it goes into InstantGo (aka Connected Standby where downloads etc. can still take place), then finally hibernation after four hours. Edit: "With InstantGo, your PC wakes up instantly from sleep with your apps and data up to date. Your experience can last all day with extended battery life so if you bought a Windows 8.1 or Windows RT 8.1 PC that came with InstantGo, there's really no need to shut down completely." - [Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/how-shut-down-turn-off-pc)

Comment: @Karan So if I get you correctly, the *Sleep* option I have **isn't** the sleep it used to be, right? It's been enhanced to sleep-hibernate. Is that what you're saying? How can I control the time between falling asleep and going hibo?

Comment: @Ramhound Not a duplicate. That answer isn't helpful in my case. Please see the thing that Karan says. I think that's the correct answer.

Comment: Even earlier if you put your laptop to sleep and it was running low on battery, it would hibernate. Now with IG/CS, updates etc. can still continue being downloaded unlike the traditional sleep earlier. The 4 hour delay between IG/CS and hibernation cannot be altered. You can use my answer to enable hibernation and specifically choose to hibernate if you don't want the 4 hours of IG/CS.

Comment: @Karan I'd like you to add the comments and explanations here to your reply. I've already given you +1 because I **know** you're going to do that, hehe. Thanks, mate!

Comment: Done as requested. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Start > Run > gpedit.msc
2. Navigate to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > File Explorer and enable *Show hibernate in the power options menu*:

   [image: 1]

Hibernation doesn't show up by default as an available option on the Surface Pro 3 because it supports what's known as *InstantGo* (previously known as *Connected Standby*).

As per [this page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/how-shut-down-turn-off-pc) detailing the various power states:

> With InstantGo, your PC wakes up instantly from sleep with your apps
>   and data up to date. Your experience can last all day with extended
>   battery life so if you bought a Windows 8.1 or Windows RT 8.1 PC that
>   came with InstantGo, there's really no need to shut down completely.

The SP3 thus goes into InstantGo mode (where Windows Update, app updates etc. can still continue unlike traditional sleep), and then it actually does hibernate after four hours. This four hour gap cannot be modified though.

Comment: As per my experience powercfg doesn't work because SP3 uses InstantGo (Connected Standby).

Comment: You are indeed correct about that

Comment: @Karan What's InstantGo? Is it something that substitutes hibernate option? How do I activate it? I'd really like my computer not to drain the battery while "sleeping".

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can:

1. Right-click the battery status icon in the Taskbar and then choose Power Options
2. In the left column of links, select "Choose what the power button does"
3. Scroll down to the Shutdownm settings section.
4. You should see a checkbox next to Hibernate.  Click it and then choose Save Changes.

(These instructions are for Windows 8.1.  if you're using a different version, use your preferred search engine to find the appropriate steps.)

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: Are you sure that option is visible on an SP3 that uses InstantGo by default?

Comment: Nope.  But it's what appears on my Surface 2 Pro.  I'm also unsure if the options can be disabled/hidden by group policy or other Registry changes.  If the options aren't there, then (again) I recommend your preferred search engine.

Comment: It can be enabled via Group Policy as I've mentioned. "PCs with InstantGo don't have the hibernate option" - [Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/how-shut-down-turn-off-pc).

Comment: I have no such option. I only have the ones that I mention in the question. Any suggestions?

Comment: According to an "official" page (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-SG/windows-8/how-shut-down-turn-off-pc), "PCs with InstantGo don't have the hibernate option."  There are claims that the following Registry key will take care of things.  In
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FlyoutMenuSettings], set 
 "ShowHibernateOption"=dword:00000001'
I offer the info for the sake of completeness.  I have no idea if it will truly work.  Practice safe computing.